# Is map<int, int>::iterator's operator<=() function a O(1) operation or a O(n) operation where n is the number of elements?

Tags: c++, iterator

Hi I have two iterators of type map<int, int>::iterator, if I compare them with "<=" operator, is it a constant time complexity operation or it takes O(n) time where n is the map size?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you actually tried comparing map iterators in that way? What was the result? (Hint: it won't work)

Comment: `std::map` provides **bidirectional** iterators. Bidirectional iterators support testing for equality and inequality; they do not support `<` or any other ordering predicates.

Comment: Thanks. Found an article to teach myself c++ iterators: https://home.csulb.edu/~pnguyen/cecs282/lecnotes/iterators.pdf It seems only random access iterators support < operator